# How to manage settings in Openshift?

Tags: openshift, keycloak

> profile.properties file not found in Source code in repository?

Is it possible using environment variable in openshift? 
If yes, how can set `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled` in Openshift environment?

Comment: Have you tried looking at Openshift documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Environment Variables are a first class concept in Openshift. There are many ways to use them:

1. You can set them directly on your BuildConfig to ”bake them into” your containers. This isn't best practices as then they won't change when you move them through environments but may be necessary to configure your build or set things that won't change (e.g. set the port number node.js uses to match the official node.js image with ”PORT=8080”)
2. You can put such variables into either ConfigMap or Secret configuration objects to easily share them between many similar BuildConfig
3. You can set them directly on DeploymentConfig so that they are set for every pod that is launched by that deployment. This is a fairly common way of setting up application specific environment variables. Its not a good idea to use this for settings that are shared between multiple applications as you would have to change common variables in many places.
4. You can set them up in ConfigMaps and Secrets and apply them to multiple DeploymentConfigs. That way you can manage them in one place.

Its common to see devs use a `.env` file that is named in `.gitignore` so not in git. In the past I have written scripts to load that into a Secret within openshift then use `envFrom` to set that secret on the deployment.  Then have an `.env.staging` and `.env.live` that we `git secret` encrypt into git.

The problem with `.env` files is that they tend to get messy and have unused junk after a while. So we broke the file into one Secret to be database creds, separate Secrets for each api creds, a ConfigMap for app specific settngs. A ConfigMap for shared settings.

These days we use Helmfile to load all our config from git based on git webhooks. All the config is yaml in a git repo (with secret yaml encrypted). If you merge a change to the config git repo a webhook handler decrypts the config and runs Helmfile to update the settings in openshift. I am in the process of open sourcing everything including using a chatbot to manage releases (optional) over on [GitHub](https://github.com/ocd-scm)

I should also say that openshift automatically creates many environment variables to help you configure you apps. In each project a lot of variables are set in every pod telling you the details of all the services you have setup in that project.

Openshift also sets up internal dns entries for your services. This means that if App A uses App B you don't have to configure A with a URL for B yourself. Rather there will be a dns entry for B and you can use the env vars that openshift sets on A to work out the dns entry to and the port number to use (e.g. dns entry includes project name and that is automatically set as an env var by openshift). So our apps can find a redis service running in the same project using that technique.